# Расположить внутренние блоки с текстом на одной линии

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок div, внутри которого находится ещё 2 блока div. Во втором - ещё два блока и в каждом из них - два блока div. Нужно расположить их на одной линии. Подскажите как это можно сделать
[image: Ожидаемый результат]

```
<div class="header">
            <div class="nameCountry col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
                <p>Россия</p>
            </div>
            <div class="countryStatistics col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-xs-10">
                <div class="countryStatistic col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5">
                    <div class="statistic1 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4">
                        <p>средний уровень жизни в стране:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="statistic2 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <p>0%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="countryStatistic col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5">
                    <div class="statistic1 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4">
                        <p>доступный бюджет:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="statistic2 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <p>0</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Установите для всех контейнеров правило [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox); `flex-direction: row`, а для зеленого также `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: а можно увидеть HTML и стили вашего варианта?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, добавил html

Answer (score 1):

Всё достаточно просто. В следующий раз выкладывайте код и место где у Вас не получается. Что-то за вас делать не будут. Данный код перепишите под свой. Прочитайте как работает `flex`

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.container');
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => cont.classList.toggle('container--row'));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid green;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  background: orange;
  border: 3px solid brown;
  padding: 8px;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.blue-block {
  border: 3px solid hsl(206deg 100% 52%);
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.small-block {
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid brown;
  margin: 4px;
  background: rosybrown;
}

.container--row {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container--row .header {
  height: auto;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container--row .block {
  height: 100px;
}

.container--row .content {
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container--row .blue-block {
  display:flex;
  width: 45%;
}

.container--row .small-block {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопочка</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block header"></div>
  <div class="block content">
    <div class="blue-block">
      <div class="small-block"></div>
      <div class="small-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue-block">
      <div class="small-block"></div>
      <div class="small-block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего всего это сделать на флексах

```css
.header{display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;}
.countryStatistics{display:flex;}
.statistic1{display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:10px;}
    
.statistic2{display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <div class="nameCountry col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
                <p>Россия</p>
            </div>
            <div class="countryStatistics col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-xs-10">
                <div class="countryStatistic col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5">
                    <div class="statistic1 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4">
                        <p>средний уровень жизни в стране:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="statistic2 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <p>0%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="countryStatistic col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5">
                    <div class="statistic1 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4">
                        <p>доступный бюджет:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="statistic2 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <p>0</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```